# Отличие http-equiv от http заголовка

Tags: html, http

Чем отличается настоящие HTTP заголовки от HTTP-EQUIV? Зачем нужны HTTP-EQUIV заголовки, если есть HTTP заголовки? Хотел узнать именно разницу между ними, и как они работают. И есть какой либо приоритет между HTTP-EQUIV и HTTP? Очень трудно найти мне подобную информацию в интернете. Есть ли официальная документация

Answer (score 2):

Из [этого поста](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42802641/11929476) видно, что нет однозначного приоритета метатегов или http-заголовков.

Из [этой старой спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-meta-element.html#pragma-directives) и [этого документа](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-http-equiv) видно, что метатегов http-equiv только несколько возможных.

А http-заголовков может быть много. В них можно писать любой текст и называть как угодно. В них могут быть данные, не относящиеся к странице. Например `Content-Encoding: gzip` не может быть описан внутри страницы, поскольку распаковать данные придётся раньше, чем будет доступен html.

HTTP есть не всегда. При чтении с диска http-заголовков нет, соответственно сделать например редирект или рефреш через http-заголовки в таком случае нельзя.

Comment: А может ли http-equiv переопределиться в настоящий http заголовок на сервере?

Comment: @AntonLogunov не понял вопрос. На сервере заголовки задаются в конфиге или в запущенном серверном приложении. Например в `node.js` их можно просто на js написать. Для этого не нужен `http-equiv`. И они никак не относятся к html.